# VC# 2010Express print open file

Tags: c#

I'm new here and my english isn't the best but I have a question.
Is there any possibility in VC# 2010 Express to print the file I opened via openFileDialog?
The opened file is visible in a webBrowser element and can also be edited but now, every time I try to "start"/debugg my application, an error message appears.
Error message:

```
"System.IO.StreamReader" does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.
```

This is the line where I need to specify the file path for the file that I want to print.

What entry should I make in the brackets to classify the file in the webBrowser element?

Comment: You need to paste your code so we can help you

Comment: you have to read about streamreader : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.StreamReader fileToPrint;
System.Drawing.Font printFont;
private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string printPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
  fileToPrint = new System.IO.StreamReader(printPath + @"\myFile.txt");
  printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
  printDocument1.Print();
  fileToPrint.Close();
}
```